# How to search for the first word in a line of a file on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that lets you search for a recipe in a file, which will always be the first on the line, however when I use the startswith() method, it says this:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

even though I have read the documentations and tutorials, when there definitely is.

I have tried this:

```
def search ():
    name = search_box.get()
    with open("Recipe_Book.txt", "r+") as dataFile:
        for line in dataFile:
            if name == '':
                pass
            elif line.startswith(name):
                close(start_window)
                show_recipe()
```

However this still allows me to search Ca to find Cake - and I cant use the .lower() method either, so that that doesn't means the user will have to always get the capitals in the right place.

**EDIT**

```
def search ():
        print("1")
        name = search_box.get()
        print("2")
        with open("Recipe_Book.txt", "r+") as dataFile:
            print("Hi")
            for line in dataFile:
                if name == '':
                    print ("HELLO")
                    pass
                elif line.split(' ')[0] == name.lower():
                    print ("BYE")
                    close(start_window)
                    show_recipe()
                else:
                    print("hi")
```

This prints to the console '1', '2' and 'Hi' and 'hi' - thus the elif, and I know that the `name` is in the file.

Comment: why can't you use the `.lower()` method?

Comment: Just an aside - that `if ...: pass` looks confusing... you're still going through the entire file... Might want to make that a `if not name: return` after `name = ...` - you'll get the same behaviour but without doing any work

Comment: as it stands your code could not throw that error

Comment: Works for me.  There's something you're not showing us.  The error message is telling you that `line` (or whatever variable you're really putting before `.startswith`) is not a string.  Either you're accessing the wrong variable or you've overwritten `line` somehow, in a way that isn't shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
elif line.split(' ')[0].lower() == name.lower():
```

This will split the line on a space character, and grab the first item, which basically will get the first word. Then compare that word converted to lowercase to the search word also converted to lowercase.

This will enforce a whole word, case insensitive match of the first word in the line.

Comment: if they cannot call startswith they cannot call split

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I assure you they can use both `startswith` and `split` with the code they provided.

Comment: I did what you said, but if you look at my edit, the `else` statement goes through, not the if or elif.